# How to cherry commit single commit in branch to merge to working directory

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, rebase

I am using Git Extensions to manage product documentation and specification.
I have a master branch (A) which consists of the current working behaviour.
I have a development branch (B) which consists of small updates where a modification to one or two files takes place per commit. This can be filled with many different modifications that we would like to make, not necessarily in a development order.
I then have a number of additional branches for big features (C,D,E).

For branch B, I may have multiple commits, each one is an improvement to be made to the software. What I would like to achieve is that once the development is complete, I can 'cherry pick' any of these commits to merge into branch A. (Effectively acknowledging that the one or two files from branch B are now the working behaviour and should be updated on the master branch).

The issue I face is that currently if I merge or rebase, this appears to update all files from branch B that were modified across all prior commits.

Is there a way to achieve what I am asking? I guess the objective is to create a commit on the working directory that has the updates of the one or two files. Manually pasting the content to these files and then committing would work but seems a bit of a workaround, and doesn't really tie together merging from my development branch into my working branch.

Creating a branch for every modification would result in hundreds of branches and may become complex very quickly and difficult to trace history of development.

Any clues as to a good workflow for management of this would be very much appreciated. I am also looking at whether or not merge or rebase is the correct tool to use.

Comment: What's the actual problem with just merging the branch? Does something break, do you want to group the commits into logical releases, what?

Comment: Merging the branch will merge up to the checked out commit so will merge everything. This is fine to work this way, but what is stopping me is that after merging onto my master, I still have the second branch shown in the branches list. If I work like this I will have literally thousands of branches listed and the project will be difficult to navigate. Maybe this is the part I do not understand well. I am mainly looking on advice for the best approach to follow

Comment: Actually if I am not mistaken that is the correct method. Create a branch for the improvements to make. Once I am happy I can merge the branch completely, and then delete the branch. 
This will keep my branch list clear. Selecting the merge commit I can still browse my one or two modified files

Comment: I don't know why it's so important to "keep your branch list clear" but yes, deleting the branch after merging is fine if you prefer.